# How to plot real time data in android?

Tags: android, charts

I am designing an android application where I want to plot real time data which I receive through bluetooth.
I receive a signal and process it to get some result and I want to display it in real time. I saw there are various android libraries for drawing charts. I am a bit confused as to go with one such library or to use Javascript. Can anyone suggest it which is a better option to go with? And also, which Android library to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to use [flot-android-chart](http://code.google.com/p/flot-android-chart/) for different types of charts creation.

or you can simply use [`achartengine`](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/)

if you want to try creating charts without any built in jars just look at this [`Bar Chart in Android With out any Built in jars`](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/bar-chart-in-android-with-out-any-built-in-jars/)(But it is only bar chart)

Comment: Thanks, but i dont wanna creat a bar chart. i want to represnt a 2D signal in real time.

Comment: What does "without any built in jars" mean?

Answer (score 4):

There are many charting libraries for android but every time I had a requirement I used android native [2D graphics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) framework using [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html). I never looked for other alternatives. It is simple and you have a lot of control. Well just to inform..

Comment: @user1693983 just to make it clear, it is not any give data -> plot automatically kind of library, here android is giving you a canvas where you can draw shapes. You will have to write the drawing part yourself. But the advantage is you have all the control and it is not difficult to create a drawing routine. I used this drawing for heavy real time data stream without any problem.

Comment: Well I couldn't find any tutorial to draw signals.. But to get an introduction to canvas you will get a lot of tutorials via google. [this](http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/06/drawing-with-canvas-in-android.html) and [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-canvas-your-android-apps-part-2) might be useful

Answer (score 0):

If you want a real-time chart for Android then the [fastest Android Chart](http://www.scichart.com/android-chart-features) library is currently [SciChart](http://www.scichart.com).

There is a [performance comparison](http://www.scichart.com/android-chart-performance-comparison/) article which puts 5 open source and commercial charts head to head under real-time conditions and in all tests, SciChart comes out on top, sometimes by a considerable margin!

[image]

This makes SciChart suitable for [real-time trading apps](http://www.scichart.com/android-candlestick-chart-example/), [medical apps](http://www.scichart.com/android-chart-example-ecg-monitor-demo/), [scientific apps](http://www.scichart.com/android-chart-example-oscilloscope-demo/) and even embedded systems which run Android as an operating system.

*Disclosure: I am the tech lead on the SciChart project, just so you know!*

Answer (score 0):

This repo look promising: [Androidplot](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot)

It appears to support import from gradle rather than keeping a jar file locally. I also considered AnyChart, but it is a pay-to-use library, whereas Androidplot is offered under an Apache 2.0 license.

Screenshot from READme:

[image: screenshot]

Just copying and pasting from their [quickstart guide](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md) in case the link breaks:

---

## Add the Dependency

To use the library in your gradle project add the following to your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.androidplot:androidplot-core:1.5.7"
}
```

If you’re using Proguard obfuscation (Projects created by Android Studio do by default) you’ll also
want add this to your proguard-rules.pro file:

`-keep class com.androidplot.** { *; }`

## Create your Activity XML Layout

Once you’ve got an Android project skeleton created, create **res/layout/simple_xy_plot_example.xml**
and add an XYPlot view:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
        style="@style/APDefacto.Dark"
        android:id="@+id/plot"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        ap:title="A Simple XY Plot"
        ap:rangeTitle="range"
        ap:domainTitle="domain"
        ap:lineLabels="left|bottom"
        ap:lineLabelRotationBottom="-45"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This example uses a default style to decorate the plot.  The full list of XML styleable attributes is
available here.  While new attributes are added regularly,
not all configurable properties are yet available.

If something you need is missing, use [Fig Syntax](https://github.com/halfhp/fig)
directly within your Plot's XML, prefixing each property with "androidPlot".  Example:

```xml
androidPlot.title="My Plot"
```

## Create an Activity

Now let's create an Activity to display the XYPlot we just defined in `simple_xy_plot_example.xml`.
The basic steps are:

1. Create an instance of Series and populate it with data to be displayed.
2. Register one or more series with the plot instance along with a Formatter to describing how the series should look when drawn.
3. Draw the Plot

Since we're working with XY data, we’ll use XYPlot, SimpleXYSeries (which is an
implementation of the XYSeries interface) and LineAndPointFormatter:

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.androidplot.util.PixelUtils;
import com.androidplot.xy.SimpleXYSeries;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYSeries;
import com.androidplot.xy.*;

import java.text.FieldPosition;
import java.text.Format;
import java.text.ParsePosition;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * A simple XYPlot
 */
public class SimpleXYPlotActivity extends Activity {

    private XYPlot plot;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_xy_plot_example);

        // initialize our XYPlot reference:
        plot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.plot);

        // create a couple arrays of y-values to plot:
        final Number[] domainLabels = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14};
        Number[] series1Numbers = {1, 4, 2, 8, 4, 16, 8, 32, 16, 64};
        Number[] series2Numbers = {5, 2, 10, 5, 20, 10, 40, 20, 80, 40};

        // turn the above arrays into XYSeries':
        // (Y_VALS_ONLY means use the element index as the x value)
        XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
                Arrays.asList(series1Numbers), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series1");
        XYSeries series2 = new SimpleXYSeries(
                Arrays.asList(series2Numbers), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series2");

        // create formatters to use for drawing a series using LineAndPointRenderer
        // and configure them from xml:
        LineAndPointFormatter series1Format =
                new LineAndPointFormatter(this, R.xml.line_point_formatter_with_labels);

        LineAndPointFormatter series2Format =
                new LineAndPointFormatter(this, R.xml.line_point_formatter_with_labels_2);

        // add an "dash" effect to the series2 line:
        series2Format.getLinePaint().setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] {

                // always use DP when specifying pixel sizes, to keep things consistent across devices:
                PixelUtils.dpToPix(20),
                PixelUtils.dpToPix(15)}, 0));

        // just for fun, add some smoothing to the lines:
        // see: http://androidplot.com/smooth-curves-and-androidplot/
        series1Format.setInterpolationParams(
                new CatmullRomInterpolator.Params(10, CatmullRomInterpolator.Type.Centripetal));

        series2Format.setInterpolationParams(
                new CatmullRomInterpolator.Params(10, CatmullRomInterpolator.Type.Centripetal));

        // add a new series' to the xyplot:
        plot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);
        plot.addSeries(series2, series2Format);

        plot.getGraph().getLineLabelStyle(XYGraphWidget.Edge.BOTTOM).setFormat(new Format() {
            @Override
            public StringBuffer format(Object obj, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
                int i = Math.round(((Number) obj).floatValue());
                return toAppendTo.append(domainLabels[i]);
            }
            @Override
            public Object parseObject(String source, ParsePosition pos) {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

One potentially confusing section of the code above are the initializations of LineAndPointFormatter
You probably noticed that they take a mysterious reference to an xml resource file. This is actually
using [Fig](https://github.com/halfhp/fig) to configure the instance properties from XML.

If you'd prefer to avoid the XML and keep everything in Java, just replace the code:

```java
LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = 
    new LineAndPointFormatter(this, R.xml.line_point_formatter_with_labels);
```

with:

```java
LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, null);
```

In general XML configuration should be used over programmatic configuration when possible as it produces
more flexibility in terms of defining properties by screen density etc..  For more details on how to
programmatically configure Formatters etc. consult the latest Javadocs.

Continuing with the original example above, add these files to your **/res/xml** directory:

##### /res/xml/line_point_formatter_with_labels.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config
    linePaint.strokeWidth="5dp"
    linePaint.color="#00AA00"
    vertexPaint.color="#007700"
    vertexPaint.strokeWidth="20dp"
    fillPaint.color="#00000000"
    pointLabelFormatter.textPaint.color="#CCCCCC"/>
```

##### /res/xml/line_point_formatter_with_labels_2.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config
    linePaint.strokeWidth="5dp"
    linePaint.color="#0000AA"
    vertexPaint.strokeWidth="20dp"
    vertexPaint.color="#000099"
    fillPaint.color="#00000000"
    pointLabelFormatter.textPaint.color="#CCCCCC"/>
```