# Java plotting library like python's matplotlib

Tags: java, plot, graphing

I am **looking for a java plotting library that might be as good as matplotlib is for python.** I have done some research looking over SO questions, but many of them are outdated and a lot has changed in the few years since they were asked. The suggestions that come up lead to websites that at the surface seem to be offering good libraries but **my needs are immediate and I cannot afford the time to use them all and find the best through experience.**

And so I am asking for your experience, can any of you recommend a graphing library that is to java as matplotlib is to python (in 2013)?

Comment: [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) or maybe even [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/) depending on your needs...Regardless you're going to need some time to learn the APIs

Comment: I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67768959/2760299

Comment: It's not mathplotlib-like, but Tablesaw's Plot.ly wrapper is a good Java plotting library. Plots are rendered in HTML/JavaScript so they can be viewed in a browser.  I use it mostly in my IDE. (There's a way to write an HTML page and open your default Browser on it.)  It supports a large subset of the Plot.ly chart types and configuration options.  https://github.com/jtablesaw/tablesaw. Tablesaw itself is a Java dataframe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a ton of graphing libraries available for Java. Plotting libraries? Not so much. A list is availble at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851035/i-am-looking-for-a-plotting-library-for-java

If none of those cut it, Here's one some quick Googling found me. While I've never used it, based off it's description [JMathPlot](http://code.google.com/p/jmathplot/) seems really good.

Comment: Hi, for quick visualization I used this: https://github.com/sh0nk/matplotlib4j

Comment: @AliAit-Bachir I was going to recommend the same library, but had many problems when trying to do simple things .... like drawing geometrical figures, or plotting points (scatter) with different colors/size - it's not supported!. However, I think the lib will be improved soon, because I checked it on github and it's active. The other recommended libraries are nothing like matplotlib, so I think it is preferable to store the data into csvs and instead of using java, use python to plot (I mean, if you can do it)

Comment: The question itself is wrong because there is a plotting library called matplotlib. Yes, one has to use Python as its command language. But there is nothing that prevents a Java program from running a Python script, either stored in a String or in a separate .py file. Just spawn a Python interpreter and run it as a subprocess. Then one can simply display the resulting graphics on the screen, be it from a jpeg, gif, tiff, png, ps, eps, pdf, or whatever format one prefers.

Comment: link to linked question broken; may use https://web.archive.org/web/20150402020904/http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions/4851035/i-am-looking-for-a-plotting-library-for-java

Comment: I wonder what the practical implications of "no OpenGL" are though.